# Is this capacitor marking in pF or µF?

Tags: capacitor, markings

Capacitor marking with line underneath; these aren't tantalum (I don't think anyway), so I'm not sure which units the capacitance is written in.

[image: Capacitor marking with line underneath]

Comment: How come you only considered options `pF` and `µF`? What about `nF` (which lies inbetween magnitude wise)?

Comment: @MEMark From what I've heard, the capacitance of a capacitor is often described in terms of pF or µF, but rarely in terms of nF.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is a ceramic disc capacitor, 47 **pF**.

Here's a datasheet for a typical capacitor of this type:
[image]
https://www.vishay.com/docs/28515/sseries.pdf

---

**A good clue:** The two capacitors, crystal, and resistor appear to be an oscillator circuit, perhaps for the IC next to them; in this use the capacitors are almost always a few 10s of pF.

This circuit is from ST's excellent oscillator design guide for these [AN 2867](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00221665-oscillator-design-guide-for-stm8af-al-s-stm32-mcus-and-mpus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)
[image]

Comment: Thanks to everyone who commented! Yes, good eye. It's in a Pierce Oscillator, and the IC is a hex inverter. The hand-drawn circuit sketch I received mislabelled it as microF, and I am very pleased that this might be what could fix my issue!

Comment: To check, will having a much larger sets of capacitors connected to this circuit, potentially cause damage to the components?

Comment: Generally it's good to keep question separate: can I suggest you post a new question with a diagram of what you're asking?

Comment: @ShashvatVerma Larger capacitance values should not damage anything, however the circuit will likely not oscillate. Check electrical description of Pierce oscillator. The capacitors & crystal form a tank circuit that needs a certain balance of values.

Answer (score 8):

> Encoding for Ceramic Capacitors
>
> Ceramic capacitors encoding consists 1-3 digits.
>
> **If the capacitor code consist only 1 or 2 digits**, it is simply their capacitance value **in PicoFarads (pF)**. For example if a ceramic capacitor has a code ‘5’ and other has ‘47’, their respective capacitance values are 5 pF and 47 pF.

<sup>Source: https://circuitdigest.com/calculators/capacitor-value-code-calculator</sup>

Answer (score 7):

That is a ceramic disc capacitor, normally you would have three figures on it, and the value is in pF; 470 means 47 x 10^0 = 47 pF, 102 = 10 x 10^2 = 100 pF and so on.

I suppose in this case they just omitted the 0 for some reason.

Rest assured it is *not* a 47 µF capacitor